# A nice property of a triangle With side 1,2,2

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

About a year ago, while using GeoGebra, I discovered a beautiful property of a triangle with sides 1,2,2.

It is that many of the important centers of this triangle are located at equal distances in a row, so much so that I called this triangle the “numbers line triangle.”

You can consider the following two images:

[image]

[image]

$G$ is the point of intersection of the heights of $∆XYZ$

$C$ is the point of intersection of the bisectors of $∆X^{'}Y^{'}Z^{'}$

$F$ is the intersection of the bisectors of $∆XYZ$

$B$ is the center of the circle $XMPDQN$

$E$ is the point of convergence of the averages of $∆XYZ$

$A$ is the point of convergence of the heights of $∆X^{'}Y^{'}Z^{'}$

$D$ is the point of convergence of the $∆XYZ$ axes

$XA=AB=BC=CD=DE=EF=FG$

My question consists of two parts:

Is this feature already discovered?

How do we prove that anyway?

Comment: Also, what is English translation of the Persian? script?

Comment: $G$ is the point of intersection of the heights of $∆XYZ$, $C$ is the point of intersection of the bisectors of $∆X^' Y^' Z^'$
 $F$ is the intersection of the bisectors of $∆XYZ$ and $B$ is the center of the circle XMPQN
 $E$ is the point of convergence of the averages of $∆XYZ$ A is the point of convergence of the heights of $∆X^' Y^' Z^'$ 
 $D$ is the point of convergence of the $∆XYZ$ axes

Comment: The text is not in Persian but in Arabic, and it means that the triangle with ratios 1,2,2 contains important centers located at equal distances in a row. @Narasimham

Comment: This is a delightful configuration. You should show it to Clark Kimberling, keeper of the [Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html). (See the very bottom of the [Links page](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/links.html).) He'll probably know if it has appeared in the literature. ... Now, do you *really* need help confirming these results, or are you just showing off? :)

Comment: What about $B$?

Comment: It's worth noting that, as named [triangle centers](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html), $F=X_1$ (incenter), $E=X_2$ (centroid), $D=X_3$ (circumcenter), $G=X_4$ (orthocenter). Also, $A=X'_4$ (the $X_4$ of $\triangle X'Y'Z'$) and $C=X_1'$. Point $B$ seems a *little* artificial here, but it completes the set, so ... okay. :)  ... It happens that $X_5$ (nine-point center), not shown, is the midpoint of $EF$, neatly sub-dividing the "number line". (That half-distance is $1/15$ of the height of the triangle, which is also the distance from $G$ to the base.)

Comment: In fact, I was interested in discovering the largest number of results in the shortest time without seriously trying to prove them, and I was postponing this topic for some time, and I will begin proving my theorems after two days, God willing, and I will prove that this result is indeed very simple. @Blue

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the center of the nine points has half the distance, but I was too lazy to look for more centers to fill the rest of the half-space, in fact, when half the space is filled, G will be further away from the base of the triangle by the same amount. @blue

Comment: @زكرياحسناوي: (Forgive the lecture ...) Math.SE is for requesting assistance. If you simply haven't gotten around to *trying* something, and the work is well within your capabilities, then asking folks here to do that work for you isn't being very considerate of their time. (It's no fun devising/formatting/illustrating a comprehensive answer only to get the response, "That's how I would've done it, but I was too lazy." Or worse: "That's how I did it; I want to see a different approach.") ... I see now that you've posted your own answer. Great! I'll leave this comment, anyway. ... Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us introduce all the points in a clear order, and show the claimed properties one by one.
To have usual, standard notations, i will switch in notation from $\Delta XYZ$ and $\Delta X'Y'Z'$ to $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta A'B'C'$.
Then instead of the points $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$ i will use (in order to avoid collisions) $P_A,P_B,P_C,P_D,P_E,P_F,P_G$ and also their standard [ETC](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html)
notations. To avoid fractions i will work with the $\color{red}{\bf 2-4-4}$ triangle!

So we want to show:

> **Proposition:** Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle with sides $BC=a=2$, $AC=b=4$, $AB=c=4$. Let $(O)$ be the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$, its center is $O$.
> Let $I,H,G$ be respectively its incenter, orthocenter, and centroid.
> Let $I',H',G'=G$ be respectively incenter, orthocenter, and centroid in $\Delta A'B'C'$.
>
> Let $A'$ be so that $A'B\| AC$ and $A'C\|AB$.
> Let $B'$ be so that $B'A\| BC$ and $B'C\|AB$.
> Let $C'$ be so that $C'A\| BC$ and $C'B\|AC$.
>
> Let $BB^\maltese$, $CC^\maltese$ be the heights from $B,C$ in $\Delta ABC$. They intersect in $H$.
> Let $B'B''$, $C'C''$ be the heights from $B',C'$ in $\Delta A'B'C'$. They intersect in $H'$.
>
> Let $B_G,C_G$ be the mid points of $AC$, $AB$. Let $BIB_I$, $CIC_I$ be the angle bisector cevians in $\Delta ABC$.
>
> Let $M,M'$ be the incenter, respectively the centroid in $\Delta ACB'$. Reflected w.r.t. $AT$ are the points $N,N'$, corrsponding centers for $\Delta ABC'$.
>
> We define the points $P_A,P_B,P_C,P_D,P_E,P_F,P_G,P_H$ as in the picture to be respectively
> $H'$, mid point of $PO$, $I',O,G,I,H$, and the point on the circumcircle diametrically opposed to $A$.
>
> **Then:**
>
> - $(i)$ The points $B'',C''$ are on the circumcircle $(O)=(ABC)$.
> - $(ii)$ The angle bisectors $B'I'$ and $C'I'$ pass through $C_G$, respectively $B_G$.
> - $(iii)$ $M$ is on $C'C''$, $N$ is on $B'B''$. The points $M,M';N,N';O$ are on the circumcircle $(P_B)=(AB_GC_G)$.
> - $(iv)$ We have the equality of (measures of) segments:
>   $$AP_A=P_AP_B=P_BP_C=P_CP_D=P_DP_E=P_EP_F=P_FP_G=P_GP_H\ .$$

[image: mse 4861319 the triangle 1-2-2]

*Proof:* Let $T$ be the mid point of $BC$. We have two known sides in $\Delta ABT$, so the third one is $AT=\sqrt{4^2-1^2}=\sqrt{15}$. The following triangles are by construction similar, $\Delta ABT\sim \Delta B'C'B''\sim B'H'A$, so we obtain $AH':2=AH':AB'=BT:AT=1:\sqrt{15}$, so
$$ AH'=\frac 2{\sqrt {15}}\ .$$
The triangle $\Delta B''B'C'$ has a right angle in $B''$, and $A$ is the mid point of the hypotenuse, so $AB''=AB'=BC$. Since $B''B\|AC$ the trapezium $BB''AC$ is isosceles, thus cyclic, so $B''$ is on the circumcircle $(O)$.
This shows $(i)$.

Let $J$ be the mid point of $B'C$. Then $BCJC_G$ and $C_GJB'A$ are congruent rhombi, since all sides have length $2$, and opposite sides are  respectively parallel. In particular $B'C_G$ is the angle bisector in $B'$ and in $C_G$ in the last rhombus. So $B'I'$ passes through $C_G$. This shows $(ii)$. Note also that in the first rhombus the diagonals are perpendicular, so the median $CGC_G$ is perpendicular on the angle bisector $BIB_I$. We record the fact, that $P_C=I'$ is the incenter also in $\Delta AC_GB_G$, a triangle similar to $\Delta ABC$.

[image: mse 4861319 the triangle 1-2-2 the other picture]

The right triangles $\Delta C'B'C''$ and $\Delta ACT$ are congruent, same angles and an hypotenuse of size $4$ each. So $B'C''=CT=1$, showing that $C''$ is the mid point of $B'J$. In particular we have the congruent triangles $\Delta C'JB'\equiv \Delta ABC$.

Before we show $(iii)$, let us cover the location of some points in $(iv)$.
For each point $P_?$ it is convenient to compute the distance $AP_?$ as a multiple of the height $AT$. We have relatively easy:

- For the incenter $I=P_F$ using the fact that $BI$ is angle bisector in $\Delta ABT$ we have $AI:IT=BA:BT=4:1$, so
  $$
  \frac{AP_F}{AT}=\frac 45=\frac{\bbox[yellow]{12}}{15}\ .
  $$
- For the centroid $G=P_E$ we have directly
  $$
  \frac{AP_E}{AT}=\frac 23=\frac{\bbox[yellow]{10}}{15}\ .
  $$
- For the circumcenter $O=P_D$ we compute the circumradius. Either solving an equation in the unknown $R=AO=OB=OC$ from Pythagoras in $\Delta BOT$, $R^2=1^2+(\sqrt {15}-R)^2$, or by computing the area of the triangle as $S=AT\cdot BT=\sqrt {15}$, and using $AO=R=(abc)/(4S)=8/sqrt{15}=\frac8{15}\cdot AT$, so
  $$
  \frac{AP_D}{AT}=\frac{\bbox[yellow]{8}}{15}\ .
  $$
- $P_B$ is the mid point of $AO$, and $O$ the mid point of $AP_H$so we have immediately:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \frac{AP_B}{AT} &= \frac {\bbox[yellow]{4}}{15}\ ,\\
  \frac{AP_H}{AT} &= \frac {\bbox[yellow]{16}}{15}\ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- We have seen in $(ii)$ that $P_C=I'$ is the incenter of $\Delta AC_GC_B$, which is similar to $\Delta ABC$. We know the location of $I$ in the last triangle w.r.t. the height $AT$, so from $AI'=\frac 12AI$ we obtain
  $$
  \frac{AP_C}{AT}=\frac{\bbox[yellow]{6}}{15}\ .
  $$
- The point $P_G=H$ is a vertex in the triangle $\Delta CTH$, and
  $\Delta CTH\sim \Delta CC^\maltese B\sim \Delta ATB$, so $HT:1=HT:CT=BT:AT=1:AT=AT:AT^2=AT:15$. This leads to $HT:AT=1:15$, so
  $$
  \frac{AP_G}{AT}=\frac{\bbox[yellow]{14}}{15}\ .
  $$
  The triangle $\Delta A'B'C'$ is similar to $\Delta ABC$, obtained by a factor-two-dilation. So $H'A=2HT$, which leads to
  $$
  \frac{AP_A}{AT}=\frac{\bbox[yellow]{2}}{15}\ .
  $$
  This concludes $(iv)$.

It remains $(iii)$ now.
By definition the points $M,M';N,N'$ are on the symmetry axes of
$\Delta ACB'$, $\Delta ABC'$, and are mirrored in $AT$, so $MNN'M'$ is a rectangle. As seen in a note after $(ii)$ there is a congruence of triangles
$\Delta C'JB'\equiv \Delta ABC\equiv CAB'$. The positions of the first and last triangle are reflected w.r.t. to the angle bisector $B'MI'$, because the common angle in $B'$ switches the sides and $C,C'$, respectively $A,J$ exchange places. Since $M$ is on the $C$-height (and on the reflection line) in the one triangle, it is also on the reflected height, which is $C'C''$.
Similarly $N\in B'B''$.

Now consider the points $M,M'$ in $\Delta CAB'$. They correspond in the congruent triangle $\Delta ABC$ to the points $I,G$, in particular $MM'=IG=AP_A=P_AP_B=P_BP_C=P_CP_D$. These segments also have the same direction (are parallel).
Observe now that $P_B$ projects on the segment $MM'$ in its mid point.
This is so because the distances from $P_B,M,M'$ to the line $C'AB'$ are known, they are $AT$ times respectively  $4/15$, $3/15$ (as $I$), $5/15$ (as $GT$). We can even compute the distance $P_BM$, its projection on $MM'$ is $MM'/2=P_AP_B/2=AT/15=1/\sqrt{15}$, its projection on $AB'$ is $AB'/2=1$, so
$$
P_BM^2=\frac 1{15}+1=\frac{16}{15}=P_BA^2\ .
$$
Putting all toghether we obtain $(iii)$.

$\square$

---

---

Answer (score 1):

This is a brief proof, I may add details later

Let's consider standard notation, then

We just need to prove that $GI=HI$ because $OH=3OG$

Applying the angular conjugation property and the inner bisector theorem, we get this

[image]

The rest of the centers are easy to show similarly because the other triangle is an enlargement of the same triangle